# How can I use UNION ALL concept in different way in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, union-all

I have one SQL query which i mentioned below, but i have used UNION ALL which is taking more time to execute. But i want some different approach to get the same details which will be more efficient. Please help me on this.

```
select creation_time, collected, errored
from batch_summary
where creation_time < (SYSDATE -1/24) and source_type in ('A','B','c')
group by creation_time, source_type

union all

select creation_time, collected, errored
from batch_summary
where creation_time < (SYSDATE -1/24) and source_type in ('d') and batch_id like '%PGW%'
group by creation_time, source_type

union all

select creation_time, collected, errored
from batch_summary
where creation_time < (SYSDATE -1/24) and source_type in ('E','F')
group by creation_time, source_type
```

Comment: This is invalid SQL, you have columns in the select list that are neither argument to an aggregate function nor listed in the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: What's with the group by? You have no aggregated values. Your query doesn't make any sense.

Comment: this is not the actual query.. actual query is huge.. but it is having source_type in select lists...

Comment: select creation_time, collected, errored, source_type
from batch_summary
where creation_time < (SYSDATE -1/24) and source_type in ('A','B','c')
group by creation_time, source_type

union all

select creation_time, collected, errored, source_type
from batch_summary
where creation_time < (SYSDATE -1/24) and source_type in ('d') and batch_id like '%PGW%'
group by creation_time, source_type

union all

select creation_time, collected, errored, source_type
from batch_summary
where creation_time < (SYSDATE -1/24) and source_type in ('E','F')
group by creation_time, source_type

Comment: @user2642751 your"big" queryhas the same problem. Remove all the group by clauses or replace collected and errored with aggregations eg sum(collected) etc. as it stands, your query makes no sense.

Answer (score 0):

Put the conditions in an `OR`

```
select creation_time, collected, errored
from batch_summary
where 

(creation_time < (SYSDATE -1/24) and source_type in ('A','B','c'))
OR
(creation_time < (SYSDATE -1/24) and source_type in ('d') and batch_id like '%PGW%')
OR
(creation_time < (SYSDATE -1/24) and source_type in ('E','F'))
group by creation_time, source_type
```

By the way, `UNION ALL` is *one the fastest* way of getting results in any set based language.